# Apache rewrite module skip paths

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how do I tell apache rewrite module to skip rewriting a certain path, currently I have the below code in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(ampache)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

specifically, I want to to let paths beginning with `ampache` to pass through without being rewritten.
the above code doesn't accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `REQUEST_FILENAME` use `REQUEST_URI` because `REQUEST_FILENAME` matches full filesystem path.

You can use this corrected rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ampache(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Or even this negation pattern will work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^/?ampache(/.*)?$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: what I want is to not redirect to index.php when path = `ampache`

Comment: yes that's what this rule is doing. If a URI starts with `/ampache` then above rule will not route to `index.php`